# Why do the voltage measured across a DC motor drop when its turned on

Tags: motor, dc-motor

In my experiences with DC motors there is thing that i have noticed where in the voltage measured across the motor when it is off is higher compared to when it is on. Why is that?

I have always paid no attention to it since the motor still spins. Is this a bad indication that supplementary components are needed.

Let us say i have a 6v volt motor and i apply a six volt to it via a driver upon turning it on it will be just 5.3v. I do not believe that the driver is the blame since i know my drivers are using mosfets and the voltage drop should be very minimal.

Should i adjust my input voltage so that upon measuring the motor voltage it goes back up to 6v?

Comment: it is unclear what you are saying ... how can the voltage across the motor be higher when it is not connected to a power supply than when it is connected to a power supply? ... the techique used for determining that result  may be faulty

Comment: @Jake: Do you mean the voltage of the **supply** is higher before the motor is connected? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: _" I do not believe that the driver is the blame since i know my drivers are using mosfets and the voltage drop should be very minimal."_ - Assumptions are dangerous. Did you measure it? To find where the loss is you should measure the voltages at all points in the circuit - at the power supply, at the power input to the the driver, at the output of the driver, and at the motor itself.

Comment: what is the DC resistance eof the motor? (you can measure this) What is the dc resistance of the driver?(you can measure this or look it up), what is the dc resistance of the supply?(look it up, or measure with a dummy load), the resistance of the wires anc connectors mtters too.

Answer (score 0):

When the DC supply sags with load current , this is a load regulation error.

Vout=Voc-I*R
 (Voc-Vout)/Voc * 100% = Load Regulation Error
(Voc-Vout)/I = effective source impedance.

R  is the total resistance of your battery or supply **and** drivers.

Generally if you need 10% supply stability the source impedance must be < 10% of the DC load resistance.

I suspect your supply is unregulated.

Motor RPM is proportional to V.out with no load. 
Current = torque + losses

You can increase the motor voltage easily 10% as it is the average power that affects heat rise and normally you want to operate less than the rated power.